# Requirements for entry into Poland on Venezuelan Passport

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, poland, venezuelan-citizens

My wife and I intend to visit Poland May 7th through 16th this year, however my wife's Venezuelan passport expires July 7th this year. We will be departing from an American airport. Will she be denied entry because there will be less than 3 months until her passport expires?

Comment: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/poland.html PASSPORT VALIDITY:
Six months remaining validity **strongly recommended**; at least three months remaining validity beyond planned departure from the Schengen area is required.

Comment: @SheikPaul the US State Department has shown itself to be an unreliable source of information about other countries' entry requirements.  A Polish source would be far more credible.

Answer (score 1):

She may be denied entry, but that's unlikely because she *probably won't be allowed to get on the plane.*  The airlines use a database, TIMATIC, to keep track of document requirements, and it has this to say:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of intended stay.

The airline agent checking her in should therefore refuse to issue a boarding pass.